# Buddypress send email notification only if user is not logged in

Tags: buddypress, email

When a member send a message to another member, the recipient receive a message in buddypress and also an email.

I want to change that because if you receive many messages, you have too much mail in your mailbox even if you are logged in : I want to receive mail only if I am not logged in buddybress.

I have find where adding the code but I don't know how to hooks (add_action or add_filter)
The file is : wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-messages/bp-messages-notifications.php

and the modification is at the end of file, just adding the if test before sending email :

```
if (!is_user_online($recipient->user_id)) {
     wp_mail( $email_to, $email_subject, $email_content );
}
```

How I can do this without change the core file of buddypress ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to filter `$email_to` and return empty string if the recipient is logged in. This way `wp_mail()` will fail to send the message and return false. Add the following to theme `functions.php` or to `bp-custom.php` file:

```
add_filter('messages_notification_new_message_to', 'disable_loggedin_email_notification');
function disable_loggedin_email_notification($email_to) {
    $user = get_user_by('email',$email_to);
    if (bp_has_members("type=online&include=$user->ID")) {
        $email_to = '';
    }
    return $email_to;
}
```

**EDIT:** A possible solution for your case with the plugin you use is to get all the users who have that e-mail and check if any is online by passing that list to `bp_has_members()` function:

```
add_filter('messages_notification_new_message_to', 'disable_loggedin_email_notification');

function disable_loggedin_email_notification($email_to) {
    $users = get_users(array(
        'search' => $email_to
    ));
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $ids[] = $user->ID;
    }
    $ids = implode(',', $ids);
    if (bp_has_members("type=online&include=$ids")) {
        $email_to = '';
    }
    return $email_to;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,

It's a good idea but I use a plugin named "Allow Multiple Accounts" which allow to have the same email address for several members.

So issue can append to use the email address to get user_id...

Is it possible to hook `bp-messages-notifications.php` with do_action at the end of file ?

    do_action( 'bp_messages_sent_notification_email', $recipients, $email_subject, $email_content, $args );

Julien

Comment: Hooking to `bp_messages_sent_notification_email` will not work because this action hook is fired after `wp_mail()` is called, and anything we do at that time would be late. Please see my update for a possible solution for your case.